# How To Show Html Code Via WebView On iOS App By Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know how to show on WebView, using String HTML Code, something like below.

This code is parsed from an XML file:

```
<htmlElement>
                <![CDATA[<div class='large-16 columns' style="margin-bottom: 1em;" id="vfwLetter">
                <h3 class="text-center">Read the document</h3>
                <div id="testeststest" class="testest"></div>
                <script src="//test.test.org/viewer/loader.js"></script>
                <script>
                    DV.load("https://www.test.org/documents/test.html", {
                    responsive: true,
                      height: 850,
                      sidebar: false,
                      pdf: false,
                      container: "#test"
                    });
                </script>
                </div>]]>
</htmlElement>
```

Does anyone know how to code to show Web View with upper source code?

Or if you have any other ideas, please let me know.

- Swift4
- iOS 10 or higher

Comment: is there any web view url ??

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There is no URL. It's just an HTML script. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way, first is to convert the html xml to html and create an empty file then save it as .html and load it to your webView.

Once you have the .html file you can do this on your viewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var productWebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "html")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        productWebView.load(request)

    }
```

Comment: Sorry to be late for replying. Your advice was so good, but it didn't match my goal. I used "loadHTMLString". Again, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer was matched my goal.
I used "loadHTMLString" to show with HTML source on WebView.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    let htmlTwitterString = """
   <htmlElement><![CDATA[<html><body>
    <h1>This is a HTML document</h1>
    <p>Hello, World!!</p>
    </body></html>]]></htmlElement>
"""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true;
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlTwitterString, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Thank you guys for helping my question!